# How to write text in Listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

This is my code to write text with a image in list view.

```
            var imageList = new ImageList();
            Image image = Image.FromFile("ABC.png");
            imageList.Images.Add("ABC", image);
            listView1.LargeImageList = imageList;
            var listViewItem = listView1.Items.Add("text with image");
            listViewItem.ImageKey = "ABC";
```

The issue I am facing is the text and the image should come in one row but currently they are coming in multiple rows.

[image]

Comment: The available ListView modes are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.view)

Comment: Please write an answer and accept it or delete the question. Resolved questions should not be left unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Klaus Gütter I was able to solve this.

I changed the view from LargeIcons to SmallIcons.

Also did change this line in the code.

```
 listView1.SmallImageList = imageList;
```